# Loading jQuery in Div

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to call a jQuery action within a div (subpage) that was generated by JavaScript. I pretty new at this so bear with me.

In the index.html I am populating a div, via a JavaScript load command.

```
    <ul>
            <li><a href="./data/new_group_form.php" onclick="load('./data/new_group_form.php','content');return false;">Add new Group</a></li>
            <li><a href="./data/list_group.php" onclick="load('./data/list_group.php','content');return false;">List Groups</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="content"></div>
```

Then on the page that is generated (which isn't a full HTML page, just a form).

```
<?php
    include "../incl/db_class_inc.php";
?>

<script>
    $('input').live('click', function(){
        $("input:.datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>

<form action="./data/save_group.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<hr>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Group number:</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="name" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Start date:</td>
        <td><input type="date" name="start_date" class="datepicker" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>End date:</td>
        <td><input type="date" name="end_date" class="datepicker" /></td>
    </tr>
```

I am trying to run a jQuery script, and it will not run for anything. I know it has something to do with the .live() function right?

How do I get this jQuery function to run in the new DIV that is created?

Comment: Tip: If you are using jQuery *and* inline `onclicks` then you're probably not using jQuery properly. Take a few steps back and look at jQuery's `live`, `delegate`, and `on` events to attach jQuery to content when it is loaded into the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am definitely new to this. I'm looking to add these features to a pre-existing page. Perhaps I will have to change the way that this pages are being linked. Perhaps even using jQuery to create those nav links, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong:

```
$("input:.datepicker").datepicker();
```

You need to delete the **:**

```
$("input.datepicker").datepicker();
```

Note that `live` is deprecated, if you're using jQuery version 1.7+ use the `on` function instead

```
$('body').on('click', 'input',function(){
    $("input.datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Replace `body` with the closest static element that holds the dynamic inputs (div\form)

Move the inline scripts to the js file (*separate of concerns*). The HTML should only take care of the presentation of the page, not on the scripts at all.